# Is the crown the only DAG whose partial order dimension can be greater than 2?

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory

Is the [crown graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_graph) the only type of directed acyclic graph whose partial order dimension could be potentially greater than 2 (given sufficiently many vertices in sets $U$ and $V$), given that for all edges, each points from a vertex in set $U$ to a vertex in set $V$?

Are there any DAGs (other than crowns) that have a partial order dimension greater than 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are many other directed acyclic graphs with dimension greater than $2$.

By Schnyder's Theorem (1989), a graph is planar if and only if its incidence poset has dimension $\le 3$. The incidence poset is always a height $2$ directed acyclic graph. Therefore, all incidence posets of non-planar graphs have dimension $>3$.

Consider the non-planar graph $K_5$. It's incidence poset has $\binom{5}{2}$ maximal elements and $5$ minimal elements (so it's not a crown). By Schnyder, since $K_5$ is non-planar it's incidence poset must have dimension at least $4$.